# Getting a pop window after submitting the form for OTP verification

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to output a pop window after my signup form is submitted. The pop up is for otp verification. I used js for pop-up but When i call the function after the whole process of data inserting into db in php the page gets refreshed as the form has been submitted which doesn't allow the popup to appear as the page is started again from first. Now either submitting the form but not refreshing the page should help but also the data needs to be inserted into db or I need a popup to hold the page not to refresh

Comment: Form is a link, it navigates to the URL given in `action` attribute of the form. If the attribute is empty or omitted, the current page is reloaded. If you want to stay on the current page, don't submit the form, send your data using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: how to use it ?

Comment: Please follow the link provided in the comment.

Comment: I used ajax and updated the code can you please look into it

Comment: This looks a totally new question. Please ask a new question instead of editing the existing question, specifically when there already is an answer to the original question.

Comment: the question is still for pop up of otp verification

Comment: I have asked another question could you please look at that

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because you are using form Action & submit button.
Instead of doing this you need to use AJAX call to PHP API/ webservice from HTML on click of Submit button.

Your API will verify OTP & give response to your AJAX call.
Once, API response is used then you can display Pop-up with appropriate message based on verification status. (i.e. success/ failure)

Kindly refer below links,

[Process for calling AJAX from PHP script](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/528a80/how-to-use-ajax-using-jquery-with-php/)

[How to Use AJAX in PHP and jQuery](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-ajax-in-php-and-jquery--cms-32494)

Comment: can you show me the code I am not familiar with ajax

Comment: Kindly refer this links
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/528a80/how-to-use-ajax-using-jquery-with-php/

or

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-ajax-in-php-and-jquery--cms-32494

Comment: Well I tried and done something but still I couldn't make a popup window any luck with that ? however I have hooked ajax with php